# zsh autocompletion for a specific program

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I have a program, let's call it `myprog` which takes a few options (`-o`, `--option`...) with or without argument.
Is there a way to configure `zsh` so when I use the `<TAB>` key it lists the options ? It is the case when I type for example `ls -<TAB>`.
Here is the beginning of the file `.zshrc` (I found it on the web, without understanding it...) :

```sh
# Completion
autoload -U compinit
compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'

#compinstall
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%U%B%d%b%u'
zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format '%BSorry, no matches for: %d%b'
zstyle ':completion:*:sudo:*' command-path /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin \
                             /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/X11R6/bin

zstyle ':completion:*' use-cache on
zstyle ':completion:*' cache-path ~/.zsh_cache
zmodload zsh/complist
setopt extendedglob
zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' list-colors "=(#b) #([0-9]#)*=36=31"
```

If this is possible (I'm sure it is !), is there a way to "distribute" this auto-completion, for example to all the people that will use `myprog` on their computer

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is distribute a shell function that does the job of generating completion matches for your programme.

If that function is installed, Zsh users will only need the first couple of `.zshrc` lines to run `compinit`.

At a technical level, there's a `$fpath` array in zsh for functions that is analogous to `$path`. Functions are auto-loaded on demand. If you distribute myprog as software, you would typically have it install the function as `$prefix/share/zsh/site-functions/_myprog` where `$prefix` is the install prefix for your software. If you're a local system administrator and want to deploy it with a tool like ansible, check `$fpath` for the zsh on your OS. Often, you can install it to a file named `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_myprog`.

How to write a completion function is too big a subject for a single answer on this site but for options you can use `_arguments` to do much of the work. Look at some of the examples that come with zsh (they tend to be better quality than others you may find). As a starting point, for what you describe in the question, you might have:

```
#compdef myprog

_arguments \
  '-o[descripton for option with no argument]' \
  '--option=[description for option with an argument]:argument:(one two three)' \
  '*:remaining argument:_files'
```

The first line tells `compinit` which commands (or other things like specific environment variable assignments) the function should complete arguments for.